# Read values from xlsx file using Groovy script in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I use following script to read values from `xlsx` file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

String filepath = "D:\\testdata\\TestData.xlsx"
String sheetName = "Sheet1"
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath))

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName)

Iterator itrRow = sh.rowIterator()
while(itrRow.hasNext())
{
    Row row = itrRow.next()
    for(Cell cell : row)
    {
        switch(cell.getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                log.info cell.getNumericCellValue()
                break;
            default:
                log.info cell.getRichStringCellValue()
        }       
    }   
}

fis.close()
wb.close()
```

I added `poi-4.0.1.jar` file to `bin/ext` folder, but got following error message when test step is executed:

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory

Comment: It lacks `poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar`. See: https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components.

Comment: @AxelRichter : I copied it into folder, but got another error message:
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script1.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet @ line 6, column 1. import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet @ line 6`

Comment: Class `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` is in `poi-4.0.1.jar`. Have you removed that now?

Comment: @AxelRichter : No, both files are in that folder, I just restarted SoapUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to keep it simple and use Fillo jar.It allows you to fire query yo xls and get recordset.
Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: I am unable to execute it from groovy script: `unable to resolve class Fillo`